# Installing thrift and pdo module for cassandra on Fedora 17

Tags: pdo, installation, cassandra, fedora, thrift

I have next problem. I am running Fedora 17 as host machine and CentOS 6.3 as guest. I have successfully installed Cassandra `apache-cassandra11-1.1.7-1.noarch` on CentOS machine. Now i need to install PDO module with Thrift on Fedora 17, so I can access the Cassandra on CentOS machine via my PHP application.

This is my first time "experimenting" with Cassandra and I have found PDO documentation on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/). I have already installed all repos like boost-devel, php-devel, pcre-devel. Problem is when I go to DataStax [here](http://rpm.datastax.com/community/x86_64/), there is thrift only for Python 2.6 version and i have Python 2.7 installed. I have even put in the yum --skip-broken which was successful and i can see thrift here:

- /usr/src/debug/thrift-0.7.0
- /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/thrift

Which is not quite as it writes on PDO documentation site (`/usr/bin/*`)

Now problem is: does python-2.6 even need to be installed, if that means i have to rebuild thrift on my own and what is then with PDO, do I have to rebuild it as well?

If anyone already did this, please provide some steps how you solved this issues.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

For installing thrift i used this:

```
tar -xzvf thrift-0.7.0.tar.gz
sudo mv thrift-0.7.0 /opt/thrift-0.7.0
chown brian /opt/thrift-0.7.0
cd /opt/thrift-0.7.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Running thrift command outputs options list, so it means that it was installed successfully.

For installing pdo-cassandra, i used this

```
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/
sudo chown -R brian cassandra-pdo
cd cassandra-pdo/
phpize
./configure
make
make test
```

After running make test i get next error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so' - /opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so' - /opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0

=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/bin/php 
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so' - /opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver in Unknown on line 0

PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 5.4.10
ZEND_VERSION: 2.4.0
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux <user_name> 3.6.11-1.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 17 22:16:35 UTC 2012 x86_64
INI actual  : /opt/cassandra-pdo/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :  
CWD         : /opt/cassandra-pdo
Extra dirs  : 
VALGRIND    : Not used
....
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with loading the module and yes module is there in that folder (`/opt/cassandra-pdo/modules/pdo_cassandra.so`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Ok. I have made it work on my Fedora 17 host. You need to do next thing. You have to copy `pdo_cassandra.so` module to the directory. You can check where that directory is by `phpinfo()`. You also need to create `pdo_cassandra.ini` file in the directory where `pdo.ini` file is. Problem is that `pdo.so` extension has to be loaded before the `pdo_cassandra.so`. After creating ini file and copying my extension to right folder I was able to use it.
>
> Also if you have problems running cassandra on CentOS (in my case it was CentOS 6.3 in VMWare) and you are getting next error:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

> You need to either edit file `/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra-env.sh` at this position:

```
...
# enable assertions.  disabling this in production will give a modest
# performance benefit (around 5%).
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -ea"

# add the jamm javaagent
if [ "$JVM_VENDOR" != "OpenJDK" -o "$JVM_VERSION" \> "1.6.0" ] \
      || [ "$JVM_VERSION" = "1.6.0" -a "$JVM_PATCH_VERSION" -ge 23 ]
then
    CASSANDRA_HOME="/usr/share/cassandra"
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar"
fi

# enable thread priorities, primarily so we can give periodic tasks
# a lower priority to avoid interfering with client workload
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseThreadPriorities"
...
```

> You need to add path to your cassandra instance `CASSANDRA_HOME="/usr/share/cassandra"` or you can add it as export `CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/share/cassandra`.
>
> Hope this helps someone, with same problem.